# Rotate animation in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation

I am trying to rotate a span for 90 deg and 270 deg, but not able to make it in css. Now i can resolve this task using jQuery.
Also when rotation is 90 deg by jQuery can't calculate span's height and block displayed in left side of div.

`var height = sender.height();`

http://jsfiddle.net/Eg8xU

Hope someone can help me to resolve this task via css.

PS width and height of each div can be different (random)

Answer (score 1):

```
.rotate {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/

Comment: As you can see i have used this css in my example, but i should to know a transform origin for each element, for right transformation (left top corner stay in left top corner of parent).

Comment: You can use margins and negative margins to move the elements around if you need too.  That, or use position absolute and align them that way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use both **-webkit-transform** and **-moz-transform**

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /*90deg or 270deg*/
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

for the dumb Internet Explorer, you can use below code:

> filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

**rotation=0 is 0deg, 1=90deg, 2=180deg, and 3 = 270deg**

don't forget to add **display: block** so they can work properly.

Here's the demo in **[codepen](http://cdpn.io/cAdno)**